# Complex plane : How to find an equation for a line in the complex plane in terms of the point which has the shortest distance?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Define $L_x$ as the line in the complex plane such that the distance from $x$ to $O$ is the shortest distance from $L_x$ to $O$. How do I find an explicit equation for any arbitrary point on $L_x$ in terms of the complex number $x$? Thanks.

Comment: this simply means that the vector $\vec x$ is perpendicular to the line $L_x$: from here you can get a direction for the line, and since it passes through $x$, you also have one point; that's quite enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut down on unanswered questions, here we go!

As [mentioned in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510082/complex-plane-how-to-find-an-equation-for-a-line-in-the-complex-plane-in-terms#comment5185541_2510082), given a line $\ell$ in the plane and a point $z$ in the plane not lying on the line $\ell,$ the shortest distance from $\ell$ to $z$ is the length of the segment from $z$ to $\ell$ perpendicular to $\ell.$ Turning that around, since the shortest distance from $O$ to $L_x$ is the distance from $O$ to $x,$ there is exactly one $x$ in the plane for which we cannot determine the line $L_x.$ (Can you tell which one?)

As long as we avoid the particular ***bad*** $x,$ we know that the point $x$ will yield the line $L_x$ through $x$ perpendicular to the segment from $O$ to $x.$